# Copy Database with Specific Date

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to copy database from one to another with specific date?
Here is the flow, the user do some action on my program (PHP Language) and then get some file. Then that file he need to upload on the other program so the database copied.

What will be copied will is only the data without structure, since structure is always same.

Example here is the structure the data

Source table called `old`

```
id | date       | value_1   | value_2   | value 3
1  | 2012-06-02 | some_data | some_data | some_data
2  | 2012-06-03 | some_data | some_data | some_data
3  | 2012-06-03 | some_data | some_data | some_data
```

and then the user want to download the data only for the `2012-06-03` to moved it into the new table called `new`. And the result in the `new` will be:

```
id | date       | value_1   | value_2   | value 3
2  | 2012-06-03 | some_data | some_data | some_data
3  | 2012-06-03 | some_data | some_data | some_data
```

Notes:

```
[*]The program will be need smart enough to understand, if the `id` already in the `new` database then do `update` if not do `insert`.
[*]The table is located on different database. e.g: `db_source.old` copied to `db_target.new`
```

What is the best logic to do that? or maybe is there already some classes to handle this kind of task?

---

*Please understand this is not college task, but real project implementation that i want to add into my program. And I'm asking here is not for `get the code` question. Please give me some clue then i will be happy to research it*

---

Already made some script that output the data.

Some snippet that do the gathering data script

```
/**
 * Get all database data and output it in array format
 * @return array
 */
function output(){
    $return = array();
    foreach($this->getAllTableName() as $table_name){
        $this->load->model($table_name.'_model');
        $class_name = $table_name.'_model';
        $model = new $class_name;

        $return[$table_name] = array();
        $this->db->where('created >=', $this->date_start);
        $this->db->where('created <=', $this->date_end);            
        foreach((array)$model->get() as $object){               
            $return[$table_name][$object->id] = $this->wrap_value($object);
        }           
    }

    return $return;
}
```

The output:

[image]

but still confused with the SQL file will be written to understand which data need to `update` and `insert`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a stored procedure that accepts the id numbers (maybe in an array or something) and moves the data. Are the tables names hard-coded? Are the databases hard-coded? You can always write a stored procedure for each table and do the logic to choose which procedure in php. If the databases are not hard-coded you could always take the in as a parameter.

Not sure the exact coding but how about something like this:

Have the @ids passed as "id1, id2, id3..." or an array. Use them with the [in](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,217174) clause. Also use [insert-on-duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO new.table (id,date,value_1, value_2, value_3) 
  select id, date, value_1, value_2, value_3 
    from old.table 
    where id in (@ids)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=3;
```

You just have to replace c=3 with your update. Here is an example of an update with join from [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,57357,57361#msg-57361)

```
UPDATE FROM tblTransaction AS t 
LEFT JOIN tblEmployee as e 
ON e.emp_id = t.emp_id 
SET t.emp_block = e.emp_block
```

Comment: table name and database name not hard coded, i added the detail how the data is gathered. Now only need to understand how to output the SQL file (maybe the sql file will be easier for later reupload on the other program)

Comment: Then you can write multiple procedures or add more parameters. Not sure how it works in mysql but in tsql you can save the query to a `varchar(max)` (string) and then run `execute(@stringVariable)` to execute it. It does make it harder to debug though.

Comment: Look into the Insert-On-duplicate. Haven't actually tried it as I work with tsql but it looks amazing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the table with the select response:

```
create table newtbl select * from oldtbl where date='2012-06-03';
```

The new table will inherit the field definition from the original table.

Comment: I think the table on the new database already exists (structure wise) and he mentioned checking to see if the datarow is already in the table as he wants to update instead of inserting then.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. We didn't need to create new table. The table is already there. The only thing we need to do is insert or update the data

Comment: Ah! Now I understand. Sorry, I will review the question and think about it.